# What is difference between web.xml and weblogic.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml, weblogic12c

Recently I started working in Weblogic server. I was trying to add runtime environment  when I added a weblogic.xml has been added by default. I searched over Internet for differences but I am still confused. Can anybody tell in details ?

Comment: followup question to this, can a single web app have both weblogic.xml and web.xml ?

Answer (score 14):

The **web.xml** file provides configuration and deployment information for the Web components that comprise a **Web application.** Examples of Web components are servlet parameters, servlet and JavaServer Pages (JSP) definitions, and Uniform Resource Locators (URL) mappings. This is located in the **WEB-INF directory**.

**Weblogic.xml** is the configuration file for all the applications lying in the **domain** created. It lies in the **META-INF** directory and contains parameters such as auth-filter,  charset-params, container-descriptor,  context-root,  description etc..

See this link.. https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081108233649AAMb2ks

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 4):

Web.xml is specific to Web applications (e.g. servlets) while weblogic.xml applies to all applications. Additionally, you need to put in weblogic.xml all settings that are vendor-specific. An example is connecting a security role with the actual user or group:

```
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>AdminRole</role-name>
    <principal-name>Fred</principal-name>
    <principal-name>Ted</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

Namely, Java EE does not specify how this mapping should be achieved. In Glassfish it is performed through glassfish-web.xml file, in Tomcat through tomcat-users.xml. One way or another, you need an additional deployment descriptor for a such task.

See also:

- [weblogic.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP571)